# Change column values but keep order in MySQL

Tags: mysql, order-by

Lets consider I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
id int,
 name varchar(128)
);

INSERT INTO student (id,name) VALUES
(1,'John'),
(2,'Bob'),
(3,'Alice'),
(4,'Don'),
(5,'Eve');
```

I need the 'names' column to exchange places with next one: 1 with 2, 3 with 4 and etc, but keep the order of 'id'. The selected output should be something like this:

```
id  names
1 | Bob
2 | John
3 | Don
4 | Alice
5 | Eve
```

Is there an effective way to write query that would give me expected result?

Comment: Is there any logic to the new ordering you're choosing?...(e.g. based on another column such as a `CreatedDate`, or `LastName`, etc) or it's random?

Comment: The only logic is to exchange the positions of the rows and preserve id column, this is just a random example that came out of my head :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self join student and use an alghorithm that fits toi find the corresponding ids

> ```
> CREATE TABLE student (
> id int,
>  name varchar(128)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO student (id,name) VALUES
> (1,'John'),
> (2,'Bob'),
> (3,'Alice'),
> (4,'Don'),
> (5,'Eve');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE student s1
> JOIN student s2 ON s1.id = IF(s1.id % 2 = 0,s2.id + 1,s2.id - 1)
> SET s1.name = s2.name
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM student
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name 
> -: | :----
>  1 | Bob  
>  2 | John 
>  3 | Don  
>  4 | Alice
>  5 | Eve
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5acf7a7aa4043db6c8dd44493609bc44)*

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an activity that a college teacher might come up with to see if someone understands math and has a little bit of imagination, as this sort of thing would almost never be required outside of an educational setting ... and I say this as someone who works in academia.

That said, one way this could be accomplished would be with a subquery that first determines the "proper" `id`. An `UPDATE` statement can then be used to match on the "proper_id" to fix the data. Here is the sub-query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN id % 2 = 0 THEN id - 1 ELSE id + 1 END as proper_id,
       name
  FROM Student
 ORDER BY id
```

I'll leave the rest to you

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this without self-joining, and without executing the same command multiple times.**

You just need `LEAD` and `LAG` window functions, and a rownumber:

```sql
UPDATE s
SET name = CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN prevName ELSE nextName END
                  -- every row is either (rn modulo 2) = 1 or 0
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        prevName = LAG(name) OVER (ORDER BY id),
        nextName = LEAD(name, 1, name) OVER (ORDER BY id),
             -- the extra parameters mean you get the current value if there is no next row
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)
    FROM student
) s
```

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2b4044bc7d5a6c8adc5b93e3e00c2fd)